# Change laravel project state

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I installed `laravel 4.2` and when I do for example:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\laravel>php artisan migrate
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************
```

Do you really wish to run this command? Y
Migrated: 2014_10_07_114534_add_authors

I changed nothing on the laravel production file. However, it seems to me that my application is currently in production? Any recommendations how to change the state to development to see all error messages etc.?

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: Just a tip, you can also specify which environment you want to target with the `--env` parameter. So `artisan migrate --env=production` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go `app/start.php` file and in

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
    'local' => ['yourpcname'],
});
```

put your PC name in local array as above or in `dev` depending how many environments you have.